# Web.config in ASP.NET MVC - what are the connectionString used?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Can someone please tell me the parameters to config, `web.config` when you have database with table on your SQL Server client.

I have a database called `RegistrationTable` and source is `Gcobanim-L\SQLEXPRESS`. Question is now how do I configure for example this below based on what I have and I am not using SQL Server authentication, just Windows authentication?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Mystring" 
         connectionString="Data Source=Gcobanim-L\SQLEXPRESS;Database=RegistrationTable; 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: The syntax coloring makes the error obvious - you missed a closing double quote before `providerName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your connectionStrings

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Mystring"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=Gcobanim-L\SQLEXPRESS;Database=RegistrationTable" />
</connectionStrings>
```